# collect all the data into a column with respective row using pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a dataframe which has columns as per the screen shot below. I want to add an additional column "all_data" which will hold all the data of the columns in it.
[image]

here is what i tried

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType

def read_file_content(file_path):
    content = spark.read.json(file_path).rdd.map(lambda x: x[0]).collect()
    return content

read_file_content_udf = udf(read_file_content, ArrayType(StringType()))

file_with_all_data = daftrame.withColumn("all_data", read_file_content_udf("file_name_input"))
```

how ever with the above approach i get error as

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 63.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 63.0 (TID 5275) (10.99.0.10 executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.ipykernel/2377/command-3710246798592077-2084292290", line 12, in read_and_collect_data
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 284, in _modified_open
    return io_open(file, *args, **kwargs)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'abfss://soruce@storage_abs.dfs.core.windows.net/bite/searc/2024/03/asdaf-adase2-47217e-31-0150bda34e47_20240308_09-19-35.json'
```

whereas the file is available and i can read in a separate dataframe

so the final data frame would look like all the columns along with that the additional column "all_data" holding the data from each file individually in the rows.

The column name "file_name_input" has the file location basically something like "abfss://soruce@storage_abs.dfs.core.windows.net/bite/searc/2024/03/asdaf-adase2-47217e-31-0150bda34e47_20240308_09-19-35.json"
and likewise there are 196 other files name and location in the column "file_name_input".

can it be possible to read all the files individually and store the data in the additional column "all_data"  respectively

Comment: can you add sample input output?

Comment: request_metadata:
{"al": "https://www.am", "language": null}
request_parameters
{"amazon_domain": "amazon.de", "asin": "'", "html": null}
results
[{"col_indi": "Yes",}], "spons": [], "sponsoro": []}
screenShot
Null
file_type_code
Keyword
file_name
ppp_aon_BRNLPE_ff_web_2024-03.json
file_name_input
abfss://soruce@storage_abs.dfs.core.windows.net/bite/searc/2024/03/adsadwd4-wewqesda-ewqe-52-23.json

Comment: output: is the file data from abfss://soruce@storage_abs.dfs.core.windows.net/bite/searc/2024/03/adsadwd4-wewqesda-ewqe-52-23.json 
in each row respectively